# Testing request with CSRF Token in Play framework 2.5 (Scala)

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, playframework-2.5

I'm stuck on a little problem with my functionnal testing.

I have a Play! 2.5 scala project in which I added CSRF verification on some forms, the associated scala-test units test failed, as expected, with the error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No CSRF token present!
```

I'm using FakeRequest with routes in order to test them :

```
val fakeRequest   = FakeRequest(GET, s"/backOffice/login")
val Some(result)  = route(app, fakeRequest)
```

How could I add the CRSF Token in order to render my test successful again ?

(Thank you, and sorry for bad english, I'm not native)

Comment: You could override you `application.conf` and set some headers for bypassing CSRF, like [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCsrf#Plays-CSRF-protection). Or look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19849420/4496364) answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me !

I should have precised that I'm also testing templates, and that I'm doing CSRF protection on a per action basis (The second case in the documentation, not the first one with a filter). Due to this, I can't just bypass CSRF as my template need a CSRF token to be present in the FakeRequest, like in second link, which I had already tested (should have precised that too, sorry), but it's for play 2.2.1, and Intellij is yelling at me "Cannot resolve symbol SignedTokenProvider"

Have you an idea how I could do that in play 2.5 ?

Comment: Found a solution and made a trait :) look to the answer I added if you're interested ^^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update : Like haui said in his comment :

> Seems like they added something similar in play version 2.6. There you can use `import play.api.test.CSRFTokenHelper._
>   FakeRequest().withCSRFToken` (Scala) and `CSRFTokenHelper.addCSRFToken(requestBuilder)` (Java) as explained in the [Migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#testing-with-csrffilter)

For people who are still in 2.5.6, my answer still apply :

So, after looking in Play-scala classes for a certain time, I finally found a way to adapt this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19849420/4496364 to Play 2.5.6

I even made a trait, so if someone need it one day, here it is :

```
import play.api.Application
import play.api.test.FakeRequest
import play.filters.csrf.CSRF.Token
import play.filters.csrf.{CSRFConfigProvider, CSRFFilter}

import scala.language.postfixOps

trait CSRFTest {
  def addToken[T](fakeRequest: FakeRequest[T])(implicit app: Application) = {
    val csrfConfig     = app.injector.instanceOf[CSRFConfigProvider].get
    val csrfFilter     = app.injector.instanceOf[CSRFFilter]
    val token          = csrfFilter.tokenProvider.generateToken

    fakeRequest.copyFakeRequest(tags = fakeRequest.tags ++ Map(
      Token.NameRequestTag  -> csrfConfig.tokenName,
      Token.RequestTag      -> token
    )).withHeaders((csrfConfig.headerName, token))
  }
}
```

To use it, simply extend your test class with it, like this :

```
class LoginSpec extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite /* or whatever OneApp */ with CSRFTest
```

then, instead of calling

```
val fakeRequest = FakeRequest(/* params */)
```

simply call

```
val fakeRequest = addToken(FakeRequest(/* params */))
```

I tried to make it look like the addToken{} in the Controller :)

Comment: Seems like they added something similar in play version 2.6. There you can use `FakeRequest().withCSRFToken` (Scala) and `CSRFTokenHelper.addCSRFToken(requestBuilder)` (Java) as explained in the [Migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#testing-with-csrffilter)