# Play Framework csrf token generation in unit test

Tags: junit, playframework, csrf

I have two unit tests that fails because of "[RuntimeException: Missing CSRF Token]":

```
running(testServer(3333, provideFakeApplication()), () -> {
    assertThat(WS.url("http://localhost:3333").get().get(3000).getStatus()
                ).isEqualTo(OK);
```

and

```
running(testServer(3333, provideFakeApplication()), HTMLUNIT, browser -> {
    browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333");
    assert....
```

How can I add a session with a CSRF token to the WS.url and the browser.goTo?

The tests are trying to reach a page that has a form.

Comment: Did you see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838347/testing-scala-play-2-2-1-controllers-with-csrf-protection ?

Comment: Yes, but I need another solution. I'm using the Result.withSession(...) approach in other tests, which works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global solution would be to use a fake application that has the CSRF filter enabled. To do that you need to modify (i.e. create a class that inherits from `WithApplication` and override) your `provideFakeApplication()` such as it creates the fake application passing in the global settings:

```
public abstract class TestWrapper extends WithApplication {
    public class GlobalTestSettings extends play.GlobalSettings {
        @Override
        public <T extends EssentialFilter> Class<T>[] filters() {
            return new Class[] { CSRFFilter.class };
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected FakeApplication provideFakeApplication() {
        stop(fakeApplication()); // Stop the existing fake app and start over
        Map<String, String> addConfig = new HashMap<>();
        return fakeApplication(addConfig, new GlobalTestSettings());
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. Awesome! Also, with this I don't need to do withSession(...) for fake requests either.